# How do I load an external json file into a webpage with jquery?

Tags: arrays, json, flowplayer, m3u8

I have an external file called `m3u8channels.json`

The file contains JSON data like so:

```
{
"title" : "ABC News",
"poster" : "http://i.imgur.com/kkb9M9C.jpg",
"url" : "http://abclive.abcnews.com/i/abc_live4@136330/index_1200_av-b.m3u8"
},
{
"title" : "Airang",
"poster" : "http://i.imgur.com/bDbObLR.png"
"url" : "http://worldlive-ios.arirang.co.kr/arirang/arirangtvworldios.mp4.m3u8"
}
```

I would like to load this data as an array into an html file so that it outputs like this:

```
<!--ABC News-->
<div class="flowplayer">
<video controls poster="http://i.imgur.com/kkb9M9C.jpg">
<source type="application/x-mpegurl" src="http://abclive.abcnews.com/i/abc_live4@136330/index_1200_av-b.m3u8">
</video>
</div>
```

For the first JSON object, and so on. I created a script in the HTML file like this:

```
function myFunction(arr) {
var out = "";
var i;
for(i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    out += '<div class="flowplayer">';
    out += '<video controls poster="' + arr[i].poster + '">'; 
    out += '<source type="application/x-mpegurl" src="' + arr[i].url + '">';
    out += '</video></div>';
}
document.getElementById("wrap").innerHTML = out;
}
```

I've tried doing this and can't even get a single object to display in HTML. I have `<script src="m3u8channels.json"></script>` in the `<head>` section but it doesn't work. What's the simplest way to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery function [getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/).

Example:

```
$.getJSON( "ajax/test.json", function( data ) {
    // do some with data
});
```